# Slick Slider Images Overlapping and Broken Buttons

Tags: html, css, slick.js

I am in the process of trying to relearn some CSS after many many years away from coding. I am trying to recreate a wordpress template by hand and have an issue with an image slider.

I have tried a few and have settled on http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ but I am having issues with my images overlapping. They are all the same dimensions and I have had a search online but cannot find an answer.

The images for the left and right arrows are broken, as are the dots below the slider, any suggestions on this?

My site is here: http://rdoyle.info/temp/

Comment: can you post the code in the question and with a JSFiddle, if applicable

Comment: its not overlapped.. i think what u need is `center:false` in your slick initialization code and also you may have to set charset to utf-8 using meta tag i hope

Comment: I did change the centerMode: false and this seems to have made a significant change but the images are not filling the entire width of the slider so you see two images at once.

Comment: I have tried to include everything in a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/4tj9tzs4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended behavior is not exactly clear from your question. If you want to make the images as wide as the slides, you need to set their `min-width`. For example:

```
.slick-slide img {
   min-width: 100%;
}
```

If you want to increase the space between the slides, you can do it by setting margins. You could set them on slides or on their contents. I personally prefer slides glued to each other, it gives me better control over animation functions. The point here is slick will auto-adjust. For example:

```
.slick-slide img {
   margin: 0 50px;
}
```

To combine the two, you have to deduct the `margin`s from the `width`, using `calc`:

```
.slick-slide img {
  min-width: calc(100% - 100px);
  margin: 0 50px;
}
```

---

Make sure you read `slick` documentation. If you don't want to be "surprised" by its redrawing process, you need to understand each feature and use it as intended. Otherwise it will work against you and, from experience, disabling internal slick behavior (without breaking its functionality) is not an easy task.

**Tip:** Set visual helpers that enable you to see elements you're interested in (I personally use red/white/black `1px` borders on elements while I build animations, to be able to see them in action).

Comment: I have tried adding this to my main.css using the class slick-slider img but none of it makes any difference to the site. Could you give em some more info or a full example, sorry I am quite new to all of this.

Comment: @DezUk, if I add the last snippet to `main.css` manually, using the dev console, images are full width (minus 100px) and centered. You either didn't save the changes, or haven't uploaded them on the server, or didn't clear cache. You're supposed to do all those in order to see changes...

Comment: Ah hat does seem to work though my arrows are now not showing properly

Comment: That's probably because you changed the encoding of the CSS file when you saved it. It has to match the one declared in browser and recommended value is `utf-8`.